# Phone Gap bug for iOS Version 5.1.1. Buttons do not work

Tags: ios5, cordova

Using phone gap for iPhone App.  The button(s) on the top bar of my App do not work when a device has iOS Version 5.1.1.  Works perfectly well on later versions as well as the simulator on 5.1.1.

Pushing these buttons has no effect at all.  All of the other buttons throughout the App work fine on 5.1.1 as long as they are not on the top bar.

Any ideas on the reason for the bug or a potential fix?

Comment: You might want to add an actual question to your question :-)